# "User-defined type not defined" error for a simple code in excel-VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a simple code to open my browser from Excel-VBA with help of [Selenium](https://codingislove.com/browser-automation-in-excel-selenium/) below; However, I got an error that says: "Compile Error: User-defined type not defined".

I tried to go to the references and add WebDriver to my Excel, but "References" option is not available under Tools category in my Excel.

```
Public Sub seleniumtutorial()
Dim bot As New WebDriver
bot.Start "internet explorer", "http://google.com"
bot.Get "/"
bot.TakeScreenshot.SaveAs (ActiveWorkbook.Path + "/screenshot.jpg")
bot.Quit
'quit method for closing browser instance.
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you ensure you weren't in break mode when trying to add references?  My assumption is *References* was greyed out.

Comment: Yep, that was part of the issue too, Tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you couldn't see References option available try to run your Excel as  an administer.